# How to grep lines, based on a certain pattern?

Tags: grep, text-processing

Let's say I have a file containing following two lines:

```
2014-05-05      09:11:53    /aa/bbbb/cccccc             29899
2014-05-05      09:12:17    /aa/bbbb/cccccc?dddddddd    16767
```

I need to get the line containing the pattern `/aa/bbbb/cccccc` only, I don't need the second line containing extra characters i.e. `?dddddddd`. Now when I tried

```
grep '/aa/bbbb/cccccc' file
```

Then both of the lines being selected. I need the full line so `grep -o` could not be a solution.

What could be the possible solution using **grep** so that only the first line gets selected based on the search pattern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the below grep command which uses `-P` (*Perl-regexp*) parameter.

```
grep -P '(?<!\S)/aa/bbbb/cccccc(?!\S)' file
```

- `(?<!\S)` This negative lookbehind asserts that the character which preceeds the string `/aa/bbbb/cccccc` would be any but not a non-space character.
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead asserts that the character following the match would be any but not a non-space character.

Another grep,

```
 grep -E '(^|\s)/aa/bbbb/cccccc(\s|$)' file
```

Through python,

`script.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re
import sys
file = sys.argv[1]
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for i in line.split():
            if i == "/aa/bbbb/cccccc":
                print(line, end='')
```

Save the above code in a file and name it as `script.py`. Then execute the above script by

```
python3 script.py /path/to/the/file/you/want/to/work/with
```

Comment: Thanks man. Btw can this be done using normal/extended regex rather than perl regex?

Comment: like terdon posted, you could simply `grep '/aa/bbbb/cccccc ' file`

Comment: But the above won't print the lines which has only `/aa/bbbb/cccccc` string.

Comment: You can match that too with `grep -E '/aa/bbbb/cccccc(\s+|$)' file `

Comment: yep, like this `grep -E '(^|\s)/aa/bbbb/cccccc(\s|$)' file`

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way would be to add a space after your pattern:

```
$ grep '/aa/bbbb/cccccc ' file
2014-05-05      09:11:53    /aa/bbbb/cccccc             29899
```

Or, to match all kinds of whitespace:

```
$ grep  '/aa/bbbb/cccccc[[:space:]]' file
2014-05-05      09:11:53    /aa/bbbb/cccccc             29899
```

Or

```
$ grep -P '/aa/bbbb/cccccc\s+' file
2014-05-05      09:11:53    /aa/bbbb/cccccc             29899
```

Or, with a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$ grep -P '/aa/bbbb/cccccc(?=\s)' file
2014-05-05      09:11:53    /aa/bbbb/cccccc             29899
```

Or, with a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$ grep -P '/aa/bbbb/cccccc(?!\S)' file
2014-05-05      09:11:53    /aa/bbbb/cccccc             29899
```

Or you can reverse the match:

```
$ grep  -v 'c?' file
2014-05-05      09:11:53    /aa/bbbb/cccccc             29899
```

Or, to also match lines that contain nothing but your pattern (no trailing whitespace):

```
grep -P '/aa/bbbb/cccccc(\s+|$)' file 
grep -E '/aa/bbbb/cccccc(\s+|$)' file
```

Or, you can just use a small script:

- In awk:

  ```
  $ awk '$3=="/aa/bbbb/cccccc"' file
  2014-05-05      09:11:53    /aa/bbbb/cccccc             29899
  ```

  Or, if you don't know which field your pattern is in

  ```
  $ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="/aa/bbbb/cccccc"){print}}}' file
  2014-05-05      09:11:53    /aa/bbbb/cccccc             29899
  ```
- In Perl

  ```
  $ perl -ane 'print if grep {$_ eq "/aa/bbbb/cccccc"} @F' file
  2014-05-05      09:11:53    /aa/bbbb/cccccc             29899
  ```

Comment: @terdon in `grep  -v 'c?' file` why you don't use `grep  -v '?' file` because file has only two lines in it.

Comment: @KasiyA true, I just wanted to keep a bit of the pattern. You're quite right though, in this particular case, `grep -v '?'` would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

To complement [@AvinashRaj](https://askubuntu.com/users/202806/avinash-raj)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/550259/283843), you can use also command like this.

```
grep -P '/a+/b+/c+(?!\S)' file
```